# how can i highlight image in android

Tags: android

My Android application have to show an image include 16 parts that download from server (for example the human
body), the user can touch some specific part of this image (for
example the head or the stomach) and this part have to be highlight in
some way (for example by displaying a dark - transparent layer around the image so 
the highlight image can see clearly  )
So how can I highlight an image when still loading the other images . 
And can I support it from 2.1OS . 
Thanks in advance !
Sorry for my poor english !

Answer (score 1):

If your big image exists from smaller pics, Java has a class named `MosaicDescriptor`

The "Mosaic" operation creates a mosaic of two or more source images. This operation could be used for example to assemble a set of overlapping geospatially rectified images into a contiguous image. It could also be used to create a montage of photographs such as a panorama.

All source images are assumed to have been geometrically mapped into a common coordinate space. The origin (minX, minY) of each image is therefore taken to represent the location of the respective image in the common coordinate system of the source images. This coordinate space will also be that of the destination image.

[**Detail and reference**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/operator/MosaicDescriptor.html)